# About the perfect residue fields of henselian valuations

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Let $(K,v)$ be a henselian valued field. i.e., $v$ is a henselian valuation on a field $K$. If the residue field of $(K,V)$ is perfect (every its algebriac extension is separable), is it true that $K$ is perfect?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Bbb{F}_p[[t]]$ is Henselian.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know what is its residue field? Is it perfect? How about $\mathbb{F}_{p}[[t]]$?

Comment: What is your guess for the maximal ideal

Comment: I think $(\mathbb{F}_{p}((t)), v_{t})$ where $v_{t}$ is $t$-adic valuation is  henselian (because it is complete discrete rank one) with valuation ring $\mathbb{F}_{p}[[t]]$. But I don't know  what is its residue field?  The field $\mathbb{F}_{p}((t))$ is perfect?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any idea about its maximal ideal.

Comment: If you have a discrete valuation then you have a DVR $\{ a,v(a)\ge 0\}$  with unique maximal ideal $\{ a,v(a)>0\}$ which here obviously is $(t) \subset \Bbb{F}_p[[t]]$

Comment: I would be so grateful if you could answer these question:  In this example, the residue field is perfect? How about the field $\mathbb{F}_{p}((t))$?

Comment: Did you find what is the residue field ?

Comment: The quotient $\mathbb{F}_{p}[[t]]/(t)$

Comment: So it is what field ?

Comment: Is it isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{p}$?

Comment: Yes. Then do you have any guess of a non-separable extension of $\Bbb{F}_p((t))$.

Comment: So its residue field is $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ and it is perfect because it is a finite field. But I don't have any idea about $\mathbb{F}_{p}((t))$.

Comment: Do you know any example of degree $p$ purely inseparable extension

Comment: Let $K$ be a field with characteristic $p$ and $p(x)$ an irreducible polynomial over $K$. If $c$ is a root of $p(x)$, the extension $K(c)/K(c^{p}^{e})$ is purely inseparable where $e$ is the inseparable exponent of $p(x)$.

Comment: But concretely do you have any example ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know more, specially about Laurent series fields.

Comment: $\Bbb{F}_p(t)/\Bbb{F}_p(t^p)$ is purely inseparable. Same as $\Bbb{F}_p(t^{1/p})/\Bbb{F}_p(t)$.

Comment: Thanks. What a bout the field $\mathbb{F}_{p}((t))$?

Comment: The extension $\mathbb{F}_{p}((t^{1/p}))/\mathbb{F}_{p}((t))$, can be an purely inseparable extension?

Comment: Yes, $x^p-t$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{F}_p[[t]]/(t^2)[x]$ thus in $\Bbb{F}_p((t))[x]$

Comment: So your example shows that the answer to the above question is ''no'' in general. Thank you very much for your time and patience.

Comment: The valuation of $t$ is $1$ so that of $t^{1/p}$ is $1/p$ so it is not in $\Bbb{F}_p((t))$ and since $x^p-t$ has only one root then the extension must be purely inseparable.

Comment: Exactly, so your explain shows that the field $\mathbb{F}_{p}((t^{1/p}))$  properly contains $\mathbb{F}_{p}((t))$, and it is purely inseparable over it. Thanks a lot.